# How to group filtered objects?

Tags: django, django-models

I have model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    _type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="TYPE1")
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

I can get the data:

```
type1_items = Item.objects.filter(_type="TYPE1")
type2_items = Item.objects.filter(_type="TYPE2")
```

I get the results as  sequentially each entry separately. I want to group them after price (amount will be changed). How to do it?

Comment: I don't understand your question...What do you mean by "group filtered objects"? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to group, you probally want to annotate or aggregate in Django terms, so check documentation; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
#import Item

def get_sum_price():
    return Item.objects.all().aggregate(Sum("price"))
```